# jquery form validation ajaxSubmit()

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-validate

I am getting very frustrated with this jquery form validation ajaxSubmit();

In chrome, it seems to fail silently without even hitting the submitHandler, firefox does, but still goes on to the action="contact.php" page. I was expecting it to just post in the background and possibly return results, but can't get it to work that way.

**Edit: Found a fix for this if anyone else is interested, put this line of code somewhere in your dom ready.**

```
// disable HTML5 native validation and let jquery handle it.
    $('form').attr('novalidate','novalidate');
```

HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" id="contact">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="email" class="required email" name="email"  maxlength="30" value="youremail @ example.com" />
        <input type="text" id="subject" class="required" name="subject" maxlength="24" value="Enter your subject" />
        <textarea id="msg" class="required textarea" name="msg" cols="30" rows="5">Reason for contact.</textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="formBtn" value="Punch me an Email" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#contact').validate({
            rules:{
                email:{required: true, email:true},
                subject:{required: true, minlength: 5},
                msg:{required: true, minlength: 50}
            },
            messages:{
                email:'',
                subject: '',
                msg: ''
            },
            invalidHandler:function(){
                $('div.error').hide();
            },
            focusInvalid:true,
            onfocusout:false,
            submitHandler: function() {
               // never hits with chrome, and alert works in FF4, 
               // but still goes to contact.php
               $('#contact').ajaxSubmit();
           }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with the validation plugin, but I would try it the other way around, by validating the form in the form plugin's beforeSubmit event:

```
$('#contact').ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit: function() {
    $('#contact').validate({ /* ... */ });
    return $('#contact').valid();
  },
  success: function(resp) {
    alert(resp);
  }
});
```

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options I have been up and down this document page and i did it the way they showed. Even tried wrapping it in a $('#contact').submit(function(){}), but no go.

Comment: Thanks. Since I found the root cause of the form not validating, your method works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

`submitHandler` is called after a submit event is fired, thus `ajaxForm` registers its own submit event handler after the submit event, which is probably too late to catch it.

You don't have to nest the two plugins, just validate first and ajaxify second:

```
$('#contact').validate({...});
$('#contact').ajaxForm();
```

That way, the validation event handler is called first, and the event is stopped before getting to the ajax submit handler if it is invalid.

Comment: what? If you do it that way, the script is gonna try to ajaxSubmit before it even validates. Basically it's gonna try to ajaxsubmit every time the page loads or refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="Form1">    
...    
<button type="submit" onclick="return SendData()"> 
</form>

<script>

$(function () {
   $("#Form1").validate();
});

function SendData(){
   if ($("#Form1").valid()) {
      $.ajax({
         url: "/WebService/....",
         type: "post",
         dataType: "json"
         //....
      });

      //do ajax but not submit
      return false;
   }
   // checkdata
   return true;
}
</script>
```